# Python Validation issue

Tags: python, loops, validation

This validation will correctly mark a character invalid if it doesn't meet the function's criteria the first time. Such as if I enter `$` it will kick it out and ask for new input. But then when I enter a correct input after that such as `fg` to get `FoxTrot, Golf`. It will say IndexError: list index out of range

Why is that? How can I get it to not do that?

```
def main():
    userInput = input("Enter license plate tag: ")
    for char in userInput:
        while(not rSeriesValidate(userInput)):
            print("TAG INVALID. Please enter a new tag.")
            userInput = input("Enter license plate tag: ")
        charToWord(char)

def charToWord(char):    
    nato = ["Alpha","Beta","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliett","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-Ray","Yankee","Zulu" ]
    word =''

    charNum = ord(char.upper()) - 65
    word = nato[charNum]

    if char.isalpha():
        print(word)
    elif char == "9":
        print("Niner")
    elif char == "-":
        print("Dash")
    else:
        print(char)


    return word

def rSeriesValidate(userInput):
    isValid = True

    for currChar in userInput:
        if not currChar.isalnum() and currChar != "-":
            isValid = False
        if(len(userInput)<1 or len(userInput)> 9):
            isValid = False

    return isValid

main()
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter license plate tag: $                                                                                                                                    
TAG INVALID. Please enter a new tag.                                                                                                                          
Enter license plate tag: fg                                                                                                                                   
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                            
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>                                                                                                                        
    main()                                                                                                                                                    
  File "main.py", line 8, in main                                                                                                                             
    charToWord(char)                                                                                                                                          
  File "main.py", line 15, in charToWord                                                                                                                      
    word = nato[charNum]                                                                                                                                      
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, as that can help figure out where and why the error is occurring

Comment: add `print(charNum, char)` and see why

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. The parentheses surrounding the condition in a for/while loop are unnecessary, this isn’t Java ;) It looks like there are some design issues, too. `char_to_word` seems to be converting the input before checking whether or not it’s valid, no?

Comment: If you could elaborate just a touch on what your program is meant to do, I should be able to produce a fully refactored version tonight.

Answer (score 1):

@alexandr-shurigin hit on one issue with the lowercase letters but the other issue is scope.  I think Python is not updating the `userInput` var in main(), instead I think it's re-declaring another `userInput` variable that only is scoped to the `while` loop.

Keep alexandr-shurigin's changes and try this for your `main()`:

```
def main():
    userInput = input("Enter license plate tag: ")
    while(not rSeriesValidate(userInput)):
        print("TAG INVALID. Please enter a new tag.")
        userInput = input("Enter license plate tag: ")
    else:
        for char in userInput:
            charToWord(char)
```

This solves the '$' input followed by a legal input.  The while-else is kind of a strange construct but legal, I'd consider separating the string validation from gathering the input.  I used it for minimal change to your code.

Comment: yep this is what it is! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because you were checking against upper-cased characters but was trying with lowercased.

Fixed it for you, now it works with `fg` and `FG` as well ;)

```
def main():
    while True:
        userInput = input("Enter license plate tag: ")
        if not rSeriesValidate(userInput):
            print("TAG INVALID. Please enter a new tag.")
            continue

        for char in userInput:
            charToWord(char)

        break


def charToWord(char):
    nato = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima",
            "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey",
            "X-Ray", "Yankee", "Zulu"]

    charNum = ord(char.upper()) - 65
    word = nato[charNum]

    if char.isalpha():
        print(word)
    elif char == "9":
        print("Niner")
    elif char == "-":
        print("Dash")
    else:
        print(char)

    return word


def rSeriesValidate(userInput):
    isValid = True

    for currChar in userInput:
        if not currChar.isalpha() and currChar != "-":
            isValid = False
        if (len(userInput) < 1 or len(userInput) > 9):
            isValid = False

    return isValid


main()
```

Output

```
python test123.py
Enter license plate tag: fGaDD
Foxtrot
Golf
Alpha
Delta
Delta
```

Comment: Sorry  Alexander it is still doing it. Look at my edit with output now. I think it has something to do with my main.

Comment: @JustinSwartz have you tried my source code? Because I've added a few patches there

Comment: Sorry I'm new to python and don't know what that means. When you enter a invalid character like $. Then enter a valid one like f. It comes up a index error. I'm trying to figure out to fix that.

Comment: Just create a new file with my source code provided in the answer and run it. It works as expected, after that you can compare your and my codes :)

Comment: yeah sorry it still doesn't work for me. Try putting the $ in first and when it asks to reenter try putting in the letter f. I get an error.

Comment: got it, @JustinSwartz check my answer now. fixed the `main()` function code. Now I believe it behaves as expected